# setting expire headers in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following in a before_filter in my application controller:

```
def response_headers
  response.headers["Expires"] = CGI.rfc1123_date(Time.now + 1.year)
end
```

but according to YSlow there still aren't any expire headers being set. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you check with `curl -I`? That should show you the full headers returned.

Comment: I see Expires: Sat, 08 Sep 2012 21:14:09 GMT in the results. Is it just YSlow being weird then?

Comment: Maybe paste the full headers if you can. There might be some kind of cache-ignore directive.